# Matlab 2021 and2023 cross compatability

Tags: matlab

I work at two computers; one Windows 10 laptop and one Windows 7 workstation.

I use MATLAB 2021a on the workstation (because it is the latest compatible version with Windows 7) and would like to install MATLAB on the laptop.

If I install MATLAB 2023 on the laptop, will I have compatibility issues in cross using MATLAB files and toolboxes on both computers? Can I just use the 2021 version?

Comment: MATLAB generally maintains good backwards-compatibility so code that runs in R2021a should generally work correctly in a later release. However, if you use new features in R2023b, those of course may not work in R2021a. The reference pages in the MATLAB documentation can help you work out when functions were introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any problem with installing the same version of MATLAB on your laptop that you use on the workstation, as long as you have a valid licence.

MATLAB code is usually portable across different versions, but there may be certain differences in behaviour, syntax or available functions, and you can check this by reading the release notes for each version (and the intermediate versions) on the Mathworks website.

Those are broad answers to your broad questions - if you have a more specific problem, and can show a code example and/or an error message, you may get a more specific answer (and may not get your question downvoted or closed).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. For future reference, where would you think it would be best to post such questions?

Comment: I would go to the [help section of the Mathworks site](https://mathworks.com/help/) and look at the documentation there, then if you can't find anything that addresses your issue you can ask a question in the `Answers` section. To be honest I think you're more likely to get good answers to specific MATLAB programming questions there than here, as well.